# What is the difference between node, peer and mininode in the functional test framework in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, p2p, functional-test

I am learning about the [functional test](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/functional/README.md) framework in Bitcoin Core. I am seeing the terms "node", "peer" and "mininode" being used. How are these defined and how are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run P2P functional tests you are spinning up regtest nodes (running simplified Python code) that connect to your full node (running the full C++ code) to test P2P functionality.

As John Newbery outlines [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19760):

> A **node** is the bitcoind instance. This is the thing whose behavior
> is being tested. Each bitcoind node is managed by a Python TestNode
> object which is used to start/stop the node, manage the node's data
> directory, read state about the node (eg process status, log file),
> and interact with the node over different interfaces.
>
> One of the interfaces that we can use to interact with the node is the
> P2P interface. Each connection to a node using this interface is
> managed by a Python P2PInterface or derived object (which is owned by
> the TestNode object). We can open zero, one or many P2P connections to
> each bitcoind node. The node sees these connections as **peers**.
>
> For historic reasons, the word **mininode** has been used to refer to
> those P2P interface objects that we use to connect to the bitcoind
> node (the code was originally taken from the 'mini-node' branch of
> https://github.com/jgarzik/pynode/tree/mini-node).

However, this [PR 19760](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19760) (merged in August 2020) has removed all references to **mininode** and so no code or current docs in the Bitcoin Core repo currently refer to mininode. Obviously previous PRs and outdated documentation outside the repo will still refer to mininode.